# assembly language coding errors

Tags: assembly, masm, x86-16

when i write code in below given manner1:

```
<------------------from here------------------------>
COMERR:                 <--------------
    MOV DX,BADCOM
    MOV AH,9        
    INT 33
    STI

SERINIT:
    MOV AX,CS
    MOV DS,AX
    MOV DX,OFFSET FCB       
    MOV AH,15
    INT 33                  
    OR  AL,AL
    JNZ COMERR               ;<== (error1)Relative jump is out of range
    XOR AX,AX
    INC AX
    MOV [FCB+14],AX 
    MOV AH,39       
    INT 33
<-------------------till here------------------------>
```

then i get the error "Relative jump out of range".
because (i think) label "COMERR:" is far enough from instruction "JNZ COMERR".

On the other way when i write the code in below given manner2:

```
<-------------------from here------------------------>
SERINIT:
    MOV AX,CS
    MOV DS,AX
    MOV DX,OFFSET FCB       
    MOV AH,15
    INT 33                  
    OR  AL,AL
    JNZ COMERR               ;<== (error2)Phase error between passes
    XOR AX,AX
    INC AX
    MOV [FCB+14],AX 
    MOV AH,39       
    INT 33
COMERR:                       ;<--------------------
    MOV DX,BADCOM
    MOV AH,9        
    INT 33
    STI
<-------------------------till here----------------------------->
```

then i get the error "Phase error between passes" because (i think) that label "COMERR:" is positioned after the JUMP (JNZ COMERR:) instruction and it should be before the instruction "JNZ COMERR:".

please guide me how should i maintain this code.

Comment: Tell your assembler it can use 386 instructions, including `jnz rel16` instead of only 8086 `jnz rel8` (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/Jcc.html).  Or if you need compat with old CPUs, `jz` over a `jmp`.

Comment: Or put your functions close together so they can reach each other with a short jump.  Or tighten up your code so you don't have to jump as far.  e.g. `push cs` / `pop ds` is smaller (but maybe slower) than mov to AX and back).  Instead of spending 3 bytes to construct a `1` in AX for `MOV [FCB+14],AX` you could use `MOV word ptr [FCB+14], 1`.  (Style note: it's a lot more normal to write `int 21h` instead of `int 33`.  Also, `test al,al` won't save any bytes over `or al,al` but it is generally better to only write FLAGS, not also AL, on modern x86.)

Comment: Oh actually both the jmp and the target are very close to each other; this shouldn't be a problem unless there's a bunch of code between `COMERR` and `SERINIT` that you haven't shown.  For the forward jump, you might need to declare `jnz short COMERR` to hint the assembler which encoding to pick.  It makes no sense that it wouldn't fit in a rel8 so `short` should be fine.